# How to catch/what to do with a WP Error Object

Tags: plugins, errors

I am running some of the WP functions directly inside a plugin, including wp_insert_post(), if something goes wrong, this returns a WP Error object, what is the correct method to catch this error? Either using built in WP functions or PHP exceptions or whatnot..

Comment: Just to add to and clarify what is said in the answers here, `WP_Error` is *not* a PHP `Exception` object. You don't use `try/catch` methods with it. But as noted, there are convenience functions to make it easy to use.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Assign return of the function to the variable.
2. Check the variable with [`is_wp_error()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error).
3. If `true` handle accordingly, for example [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) with message from [`WP_Error->get_error_message()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Error#Methods) method.
4. If `false` - proceed as usual.

Usage:

```
function create_custom_post() {
  $postarr = array();
  $post = wp_insert_post($postarr);
  return $post;
}

$result = create_custom_post();

if ( is_wp_error($result) ){
   echo $result->get_error_message();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Hei,

first, you check weather your result is a `WP_Error` object or not:

```
$id = wp_insert_post(...);
if (is_wp_error($id)) {
    $errors = $id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error; //this is just an example and generally not a good idea, you should implement means of processing the errors further down the track and using WP's error/message hooks to display them
    }
}
```

This is the usual way.

But the WP_Error object can be instanciated without any error occuring, just to act as a general error store just in case. If you want to do so, you can check if there are any errors by using `get_error_code()`:

```
function my_func() {
    $errors = new WP_Error();
    ... //we do some stuff
    if (....) $errors->add('1', 'My custom error'); //under some condition we store an error
    .... //we do some more stuff
    if (...) $errors->add('5', 'My other custom error'); //under some condition we store another error
    .... //and we do more stuff
    if ($errors->get_error_code()) return $errors; //the following code is vital, so before continuing we need to check if there's been errors...if so, return the error object
    .... // do vital stuff
    return $my_func_result; // return the real result
}
```

If you do that, you can then check for an process the returned error just as in the `wp_insert_post()` example above.

The Class is [documented on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Error).
And there's also [a little article here](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/05/04/error-management-for-wordpress-plugins/).

Comment: Thanks! Yours first snippet did the work for wp_insert_user.

Answer (score 1):

```
$wp_error = wp_insert_post( $new_post, true); 
                              echo '<pre>';
                              print_r ($wp_error);
                              echo '</pre>';
```

This will show you exactly what's wrong with wordpress post insert function. just try it !