# wp_mail send multiple emails in a loop

Tags: email, wp-mail

I'm very confused with wp_mail(). Here my code.

```php
function email_notification_for_admin_and_customer( $order_data ) {
    $subject_email = 'Subject LOREM IPSUM';
    $customer_email = 'Hi Customer, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus, dui eget luctus accumsan, turpis orci malesuada turpis, eget volutpat ante velit a quam.';
    $admin_email = 'Hi Admin, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus, dui eget luctus accumsan, turpis orci malesuada turpis, eget volutpat ante velit a quam.';
    $send_email = array(
        array(
            'to' => 'email_1@example.com',
            'subject' => $subject_email,
            'message' => $customer_email
        ),
        array(
            'to' => 'email_2@example.com',
            'subject' => $subject_email,
            'message' => $admin_email
        )
    );

    foreach ($send_email as $key => $value) {
        wp_mail( $value['to'], $value['subject'], $value['message']);
    }

}
```

I want to send email notification to the admin and customer, but wp_mail() only sends first email, which is to customer. Can you help me. Thank you.

I have same problem with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197907/calling-wp-mail-twice-in-same-function-the-second-one-will-not-be-sent), but with different case.

**UPDATE THE ANSWER**

I'm using the wp_mail filter to format wordpress plain email into my html email template.

```php
add_filter('wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_filter');
function my_wp_mail_filter($args) {
    $message = $args['message'];
    $args['message'] = wpet_email_template(apply_filters('wpet_filter_email', $message));
    return $args;
}
```

This is the function to include html template.

```php
function wpet_email_template($message) {

    // Render Template
    ob_start();
    include('custom-email-template.php');
    $wpet_template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Replace Placeholder
    $message = str_replace('%%MAILCONTENT%%', $message, $wpet_template);

    // Return Template with Data
    return $message;
}
```

The problem is **include_once('custom-email-template.php');**
then I change to **include('custom-email-template.php');**

So this is the problem why the email just sent to customer email (first array of $send_email).

Here [the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/369006/wp-mail-send-multiple-emails-in-a-loop#comment536876_369006)

Comment: `wp_mail` returns a `true` and `false` value to indicate success, but your code doesn't bother to check for this and just assumes that it worked. How are you populating the `$send_email` array? I'm assuming you're using actual data in your code, but we can't see that so we can't eliminate it as a possible cause. Is there anything in your PHP error log? `@example.com` is a test domain, it won't send emails to `example.com`

Comment: I have return `$send_email` array on this function and there's no error. I see the `$send_email` array data as I wish. but the problem is when calling `wp_mail`. Is `wp_mail` can't call twice? You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197907/calling-wp-mail-twice-in-same-function-the-second-one-will-not-be-sent . I have same problem with this but with different case.

Comment: You wouldn't see an error in $send_mail, no. You should check the return value of wp_mail() to see if there are any errors, or hook [wp_mail_failed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11141/how-to-catch-what-to-do-with-a-wp-error-object) and log any errors out (e.g. there's an example in the ['Debugging wp_mail (after WordPress 4.4)' section on this page](https://www.codeforest.net/debugging-wp-mail-like-a-boss-debugger)). I don't know of any reason you can't call wp_mail() twice, but it's obvious something is breaking it in your case yes.

Comment: I got error message "Message body empty". By the way, I'm using template for default wp_mail(). Here's my code https://gist.github.com/dhmskrn/7015bc49606d472aaac9346448b02834

Comment: I try to send message with wp_mail without template (plain text) , call wp_mail() twice and it works.. So, I think the problem came from the template.

Comment: @DhimasKirana can you update your question to include your code? What's in your gist and what's in your question are very different, and people don't normally read the comments so they won't see your gist. Also your Q becomes useless to other people with this problem if gist goes down, or you delete it. Edit: I looked at the gist and could not find any calls to `wp_mail`. I'm also seeiing a lot of unknown functions and fiilters starting with the nws prefix, are you using a custom email plugin?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, i'm using own custom email plugin. the gist contain function to add custom email template to all emails via `wp_mail`. but when I call `wp_mail` twice to send multiple email with different message, the second call fails. But i didn't found the error on own custom email plugin.

Comment: Does it work without your plugin? To debug this we'd need to either eliminate to plugin as a cause by testing it without the plugn, or by debugging the plugin which means we would need to see the entire plugin. There are too many moving parts right now to just work with `wp_mail` on its own, and lots of parts that aren't viewable to us

Comment: @TomJNowell Hi' I have found the problem. You can see in my gist on line 8. I'm using `include_once`. So when I call `wp_mail` again, the template file doesn't loaded properly. So I got error message "Message body empty". You can close this thread. Thank you.

Comment: @DhimasKirana if you have found the answer, can you write it up as an answer? This isn't a dicussion forum/thread, the question needs an answer, these are just comments for asking clarifying questions to help understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Function `wp_mail()` not suitable for use in a loop.

Unfortunately, a loop iterating over and over hundreds of times could considerably slow down the script, as pointed out in the reference on the PHP_mail() function. It is worth nothing that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient and have many failures while the loop is running - I found this information in SmashingMagazine's Book about Customazing Wordpress, published on March 2016.

I advise to divide the functionality of sending email notifications to admins and customers.

```
function email_notification_for_customer( $order_data ) {    
    
    $subject_email = 'Subject LOREM IPSUM';
    $customer_email = 'Hi Customer, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus, dui eget luctus accumsan, turpis orci malesuada turpis, eget volutpat ante velit a quam.';  
    
    /* send to list of customers mails */
    $send_email_to = array(
        'email_1@example.com',
        'email_1@example.com',
        'email_1@example.com',
        'email_1@example.com',
        'email_1@example.com'
    );  

    wp_mail( send_email_to, $subject_email, $customer_email);
}

function email_notification_for_admin( $order_data ) {
    
    $subject_email = 'Subject LOREM IPSUM';
    $admin_email = 'Hi Admin, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tempus, dui eget luctus accumsan, turpis orci malesuada turpis, eget volutpat ante velit a quam.';
    
    /* send to single admin's mail */
    $send_email_to = array(
        'email_2@example.com'
    );

    wp_mail( $value['to'], $subject_email, $admin_email);
}
```

Comment: "not suitable for use in a loop" - why not?

Comment: Why do you need to use this in a loop, if it is already a wrapper for `PHPMailer`, with all the loops inside? With my answer I wanted to suggest that the option of using `wp_mail()` in a loop is the wrong architectural approach.

Comment: Note that by using the `to` field you're exposing customer emails it should be BCC if one email is being sent to multiple recipients

Comment: I added more detailed explanation to answer post.